# CSS/SCSS select element not having successor with class

Tags: css, sass

I have the following html:

```
<ul class="pagination ">
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page5">
            <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page3">3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page4">4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page5">5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="/en/products/page6">6</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hide">
        <a href="/en/products/page7">
            <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In this example, I'm on the last page, so the 'next page' button is automatically hidden.
I want the last visible item (page 6) to have rounded borders.
How can I select 'page 6' with css/scss without changing the HTML?
I thought about something like this:

```
.pagination > li:not( + li.hide) > a,
.pagination > li:not( + li.hide) > span {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

But this doesn't work.
Just to be clear: I want to select the item before the `.hide` without depending on the `.active` class.

Comment: in css there is no way. so use javascript to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:nth-last-child()` selector to start from the end of the list of items and select the second to last item you have. Here is [how `nth-last-child` works](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-last-child/).

```css
.pagination > li {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.pagination > li.active:nth-last-child(2) {
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}

.pagination > li.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pagination ">
  <li class="">
      <a href="/en/products/page5">
          <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
      <a href="/en/products/page1">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
      <a href="/en/products/page2">2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
      <a href="/en/products/page3">3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
      <a href="/en/products/page4">4</a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
      <a href="/en/products/page5">5</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
      <a href="/en/products/page6">6</a>
  </li>
  <li class="hide">
      <a href="/en/products/page7">
          <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this with css alone.

I know you haven't tagged your question with javascript or jquery, but here is a solution using CSS and jQuery that may help.

I've used `color` property instead of `border` for simplicity.

```js
$('.hide').prev("li").find("a").addClass('border');
```

```css
.border {
  color: red;
}

.pagination > li:last-child:not(.hide) > a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination ">
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page5">
            <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page3">3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page4">4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page5">5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="/en/products/page6">6</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hide">
        <a href="/en/products/page7">
            <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>arrow</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="pagination ">
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page5">
            <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page3">3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page4">4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/en/products/page5">5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="/en/products/page6">6</a>
    </li>
   
</ul>
```